# I want to change file directory on git command

Tags: bash, command

I just begin coding with bash prompt and I want to change file directory.
When I type

```
$ cd ~/Users/Desktop/Bioinfo_pro/
```

I get this message:

> ```
> bash: cd: /c/Users/m_abo/Users/Desktop/Bioinfo_pro/: No such file or directory
> ```

Comment: Does the directory `/c/Users/m_abo/Users/Desktop/Bioinfo_pro/` really exists?

Comment: @Aboalmagd : The message just says that there is no such directory `Desktop/Bioinfo_pro` under your home directory. You could do a `ls -R ~` or a `find ~ -type d` to see what directories exist there.

Comment: Can you share the bash script?